# How to fine tune input parameters for ALWRS Factorizer in Apache Mahout?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, svd

So I have been using Apache Mahout for building a recommendation system. I am interested in using the SVD matrix factorization method.

I would like to know how I can fine tune the input paramter for :
ALSWRFactorizer(dataModel, no_of_hidden_features, lambda, iterations)

I have tried varying the values of lamda from 0.05 - 0.065 and my recommendation scores increased and then decreased. I thus selected 0.05945 as the value where the scores had reached the peak.

Is this the only approach I can use to estimate no_of_iterations and hidden_features. (values are rising and then decreasing, I expect no-of_features to be between 20-30).

Moreover is this the right approach even?

EDIT: Well I ran a couple more tests, and I seem to have zeroed in on using 20 hidden features, lambda = 0.0595, 20 iterations.

However I'd appreciate any answers explaining how I can do it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this paper:
[Application of Dimensionality Reduction in Recommender System](http://files.grouplens.org/papers/webKDD00.pdf)

In section 4.3 they have essentially followed the same steps that I have done. After spending a day or two going through google results, iterative experimentation seems to be the only answer to fine tune these paramters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean that your "scores" increased then decreased. If you are describing running a precision type cross-validation test after applying each parameter iteration then you did the right thing. The values you came up with are very close to the "rules of thumb" for ALS-WR.

Comment: sorry I did not make that clear enough. Yes, that is what I did. Thanks